# Twilio Sms not sending Php

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to send sms using twilio but not getting any response or unable to send sms
I am using following code,where i am wrong ?

```
require __DIR__ . 'Twilio/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;
$sid    = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$token  = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$message = $twilio->messages
                  ->create("+91xxxxxxx", // to verified twilio number
                           array(
                               "body" => "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?",
                               "from" => "+xxxxxxx"
                           )
                  );
print($message->sid);
```

Comment: Is there any messages in the Twilio debug log?

Comment: are you using a sandbox or live details?

Comment: @Gulshan: i am using sandbox detail and sending sms to verified numbers

Comment: @Hoppeduppeanut: no, nothing showing in debug log

Comment: if you *var_dump($message)*, what it returns?

Comment: @Gulshan: return nothing

Comment: could you please init your error_reporting, i thing there are other issue

Comment: Login to Twilio and see if it received the message

Answer (score 0):

Following reasons may possible in this case.

1. Make sure that you have CURL module enable
2. var_dump($message);
3. Try to print Twilio object $twilio to make sure that library is correctly loaded .
4. Turn on php error by adding top of the script

   error_reporting(E_ALL);

   ini_set('display_errors','1');

Comment: now i am getting following error

The From phone number +786xxxxx is not a valid,

Comment: @nehakhurana you have to use this phone number format (+)(country code)(phone number)

Comment: @nehakhurana Are you getting anything ?